# Generating jpg images of Questions and Options in Exam Document Class through any method

Tags: luatex, tex4ht, exam, htlatex

The following is a code of TeX file.

```
 \documentclass{exam}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
    \question  Sample Question
    \begin{choices}
    \choice choice 1
    \choice choice 2
    \choice choice 3
    \choice choice 4
    \end{choices}
    \end{questions}
    \end{document}
```

Is it possible to have make4ht or htlatex or lua Code or any other method which will produce jpg image of each question and each option (so sample question in above tex file will generate five images : one for question and other for four options.) The jpg file should not include question number and option label. At the end images are to be named as `1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg, 4.jpg, 5.jpg` for question 1 and its four options. The second question will have five images named as `6.jpg, 7.jpg, 8.jpg, 9.jpg, 10.jpg`and so on.

Comment: Hmmm... so there are two different `5.jpg`? What is the final objective? This question seems a bit an XY question...

Comment: could you please update your MWE with full preamble? I don't know where are the `\question` command and `choices` environment defined.

Comment: I have updated for both comments. It is exam document class and there was typo: 5.jpg was repeated.

Comment: @Rmano The final objective is to produce images for questions and options which are to be uploaded in some software used for conducting examinations. The software doesn't support latex but support images...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

% this counter will be used for picture numbering
\newcount\choicespic

% configure pictures to be .jpg
\Configure{Picture}{.jpg}

\def\setupnextpicture{%
  \global\advance\choicespic by 1%
  \NextPictureFile{\the\choicespic}%
}

% configure markup and images for the choices environemnt
\ConfigureList{choices}
{\let\origchoice\choice\HCode{</div>}\def\choiceend{}}% 
{\choiceend\let\choice\origchoice}
{%
  \choiceend\HCode{<div class="choice">}%
  \def\choiceend{\HCode{</div>}}% 
  % update image name
}
{
  \setupnextpicture% declare new picture name
  \Picture*{}% start picture
  \def\choice{\EndPicture\origchoice}% close picture before every \choice command
}
% close picture at end of the choices environment
\AtEndEnvironment{choices}{\EndPicture}
% close \question picture
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{choices}{\EndPicture}

\makeatletter
% save original version of questions environemtn
\let\orig@questions\questions
% redefine the \process@question command to start the picture
\def\questions{%
 \orig@questions% execute the original code
 \let\origprocessquestion\process@question % save \process@question
 \def\process@question{\origprocessquestion\setupnextpicture\Picture*{}}%
}
 
\makeatother

\ConfigureList{questions}
{%
 \def\questionlistend{} % reset questionlistend
 \AnchorLabel\SkipRefstepAnchor% remove link inserted by \label
 \Configure{()}{$}{$}% disable pictures for math
}
{\questionlistend}
{%
  \ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\questionlistend%
  \HCode{<div class="question"><div class="questiontitle">}%
  \def\questionlistend{\HCode{</div>}%
  \AnchorLabel\SkipRefstepAnchor%
}
}
{}%{\setupnextpicture\Picture*{}}

\AtEndEnvironment{questions}{\HCode{</div>}}


\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The problem with the `exam` class is that it defines some commands that are active only inside environments, so it is quite difficult to patch them.

Compile using

```
make4ht -c config.cfg exam.tex
```

This is the result:

[image]

And HTML:

```html
  <div class='questions'>
    <a id='x1-3x1'></a><div class='question'><div class='questiontitle'>
 1. <img alt='Sample Question  ' src='1.jpg' />
            </div><div class='choice'>
         A.  <img alt='choice 1  ' src='2.jpg' />
            </div><div class='choice'>
         B.  <img alt='choice 2  ' src='3.jpg' />
            </div><div class='choice'>
         C.  <img alt='choice 3  ' src='4.jpg' />
            </div><div class='choice'>
         D.  <img alt='choice 4  ' src='5.jpg' /></div>
 2. <img alt='Second Question  ' src='6.jpg' />
            </div><div class='choice'>
            <a id='x1-82'></a>A. <img alt='choice 5  ' src='7.jpg' />
            </div><div class='choice'>
         B.  <img alt='choice 6  ' src='8.jpg' />
            </div><div class='choice'>
         C.  <img alt='choice 7  ' src='9.jpg' />
            </div><div class='choice'>
         D.  <img alt='choice 8  ' src='10.jpg' /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not getting expected output. I am running it with the command `make4ht -uc config.cfg exam.tex html5` Here are my files. https://easyupload.io/y5j3io
There are certain problems: Images for questions are not generated and Images should not contain question number or option label such as A, B, C, D. 
Probably it may not possible to achieve this in make4ht. Thanks for all your efforts.

Comment: @user61681 I think it will be possible, I just didn't read your question patiently, so I messed that you want to make images withouut labels.

Comment: @user61681 I've added the update cfg file. It now includes the question title and excludes labels.

Comment: Thanks for your updated answer. Some Strange thing is happening. Unless I use package`parskip`, I am getting the error `Undefined control sequence. l.29 \AtEndEnvironment {choices}{\EndPicture}`
If I use package parskip, only one image is generated. Here are my files. 
https://easyupload.io/umk80p
Can you please look into the issue? I can't figure it out.

Comment: Here is the link for project which you can edit https://www.overleaf.com/2452698357gpqgshfhmvdq Generated files can be viewed as described here https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/View_generated_files

Comment: @user61681 I think that old version of LaTeX is used on Overleaf, `\AtEndEnvironment` had been added relatively recently. I will try to come with a solution that uses some alternative to that.

Comment: @user61681 no, it get too messy without these commands. You can try this method for compiling on Overleaf: https://www.kodymirus.cz/overleaf-html-sample/main.html

Comment: Thanks for all your efforts and response. It works when LaTeX is updated to newest versions.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work when Mathematics Environment is involved. Here are sample files. https://easyupload.io/9vybsv Also when there are two or more lines in question, alignment gets disturbed. Can you figure it out? It is just containing one question.

Comment: @user61681 I've updated the .cfg file. It doesn't work correctly for your original test file, but it works for the file you send in the comments.

Comment: I can't thank you enough. You are Great...!!! I salute to your expertise and dedication...Thanks...

Comment: @user61681 Thank you for your kind words. I am happy that it finally works, it was a lot harder than I expected :)